# How to get The Pitt slave clothes, after already looting the slave camp

Tags: fallout-3

The prerequisite for starting The Pitt DLC is to find slave clothes.

I already freed the slaves in question and looted the body in the slave pens long before I tried to start The Pitt DLC. This means that simply getting clothes from the area by the objective marker is not an option.

Is there any in game or other cheating solution to acquire appropriate clothes to start this DLC or to enter it anyway? Are there detailed enough save editing application out there?

I am playing on the Xbox 360. (Yes I know that was a poor choice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reload the save before talking to Werner. Choose the dialogue option declining to use a disguise.

Comment: This question pushed me over the sedge as far as playing skyrim on the pc rather than xbox. Or was it the thousands of cheese wheel videos. I'll leave that one to the philosophers.

Comment: BUT. I can't reload it :( No other option?

Comment: @Chilion. Not as far as I know. If you start a new character I think you can jump almost straight into dlc, you might how to lower the difficultly.